# Visual Studio 2013 auto indent

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

In Visual Studio 2013, under Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension, I have set three file extensions, namely .cginc, .compute, and .shader (these are Unity3D shader files) to use Microsoft Visual C++ for auto formatting.

Sometimes auto indent (for curly braces) works, and sometimes it doesn't...I can't find any rhyme or reason for this. When it doesn't work, it starts every new line flush to the left.

I Google around every couple weeks and can't find an answer.

Does anyone know any setting to make auto indent work consistently?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Tools -> Options -> Select the language of your choice (Expand the menu) -> Select Formatting (Expand this sub menu) -> Select Indendation

Once you have selected Indentation, on the right are options displayed - Check/Tick the option: **Indent Braces**.

Note: You may also format the entire document/file using the shortcut **Ctrl+K+D**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't seem to affect custom file extensions that are mapped to another languages format settings.